# JAutomate-GUI testing

Tags: automated-tests, gui-testing

What is the JAutomate testing tool? I have been asked to do case study about it and I am not able find much information about it. I checked http://jautomate.com/ but there no finer details about the pros, cons, comparisons and scope of this tool. Would be really glad if someone throws some light about this tool's architecture, limitations, other such gui tools which use image comparison and JAutomate's scope.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

JAutomate is a test automation tool based on image recognition. There are other image recognition based tools like Sikuli, SeeTest and EggPlant. JAutomate supports both small images, like the other tools mentioned, but also something called AI images that are small screenshots. The main advantage of using AI images is that the small screenshots provide more information about the target than small images. The extra information, in the screenshot, can be used to eliminate false targets and to provide tolerance for deviations.